# Espresso : Unable to pick image from gallery

Tags: android, android-espresso

Using espresso I need to pick an image from gallery and display it in ImageView.

In my case the onActivityResult is getting called but I am not getting data in the intent to display the image.

Can anyone please suggest what I doing wrong here??

Below is my code

```
public void test() {
    Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = AllOf.allOf(IntentMatchers.hasAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK),
                IntentMatchers.hasData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI));
        Intents.init();

        Intents.intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, getGalleryIntent()));

        Espresso.onView(isRoot()).perform(waitFor(1000));

        Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.choose)).perform(click());

        Intents.intended(expectedIntent);
        Intents.release();
}

private Intent getGalleryIntent() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        ArrayList<Parcelable> parcels = new ArrayList<>();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("file://storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170427_190140.jpg");
        Parcelable parcelable1 = uri1;
        parcels.add(parcelable1);
        bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, parcels);
        // Create the Intent that will include the bundle.
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        return intent;
    }
```

Comment: did you solve it??

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't work for me as well, the data was null.
Here's what did:

```
private Intent getGalleryIntent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/337663"));

    return intent;
}
```